# Find a date inside range with for loop

Tags: excel, vba, date, for-loop, find

I think is an easy one (not for a excel VBA dummy like me...)
I'm trying to find a date (hour format) (writen in another cell C5) inside a range of dates.
The code is the following one, but I receive nothing as an output, and I do not understand why... Thank you in advance for your help...

```
Sub recorrer()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Sheets("General").Activate

Set rng = Range("A22", Range("A22").End(xlDown))

For Each cell In rng
    If DateDiff("h", Sheets("Hoja1").Range("C5").Value, cell.Value) < 0 Then
    cell = Sheets("Hoja1").Range("C2").Value
    End If
Exit For

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Handling Dates in VBA

```vb
Sub Recorrer()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

    ' Source (read from)
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Hoja1")
    Dim sCompareValue As Variant: sCompareValue = sws.Range("C5").Value
    Dim sReplaceValue As Variant: sReplaceValue = sws.Range("C2").Value
    
    ' Destination (write to)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("General")
    Dim drg As Range
    Set drg = dws.Range("A22", dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    
    If Not IsDate(sCompareValue) Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim dCell As Range
    Dim dValue As Variant
    
    For Each dCell In drg.Cells
        dValue = dCell.Value
        If IsDate(dValue) Then ' is a date
            If DateDiff("h", sCompareValue, dValue) < 0 Then ' criteria met
                dCell.Value = sReplaceValue
                ' If you want to do it only to the first cell
                ' that meets the criteria, you will use:
                'Exit For
            'Else ' criteria not met
            End If
        'Else ' is not a date
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you indent your code properly, you can see that your `Exit For` will be executed after the first cell is checked every time.

```vb
Sub recorrer()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Sheets("General").Activate
    
    Set rng = Range("A22", Range("A22").End(xlDown))
    
    For Each cell In rng
        If DateDiff("h", Sheets("Hoja1").Range("C5").Value, cell.Value) < 0 Then
            cell = Sheets("Hoja1").Range("C2").Value
        End If
        Exit For
    Next
End Sub
```